# multi-line proof using proof package

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I have been using the infer from the proof package. I am wondering if there is a way to add line breaks in the proofs? For instance I would like to set:

```
  A
B   C 
-----
  D
```

But I couldn't find a way to do so. I have tried using \linebreak, \, and the multline environment but none of those worked.

Comment: What's wrong with `\deduce{\infer{D}{B & C}}{A}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be problems with the `matrix` environment, but the array environment seems to do what you seem to want. It would be nice to know what that arrangement is supposed to mean. Anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof}
\begin{document}
\infer{D}{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}} &A&\\B&&C\end{array}}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dan -- it means the same as (A B C) -> C. Just putting it in two lines due to space constraints.

Comment: @Dan -- what problems are you referring to regarding the `amsmath` environments?  if there's a real bug, i'd like to add it to the list.

Comment: @barbarabeeton As it turns out, nothing. I first tried `matrix`, which I somehow got into my head was an amsmath environment. It turns out that it conflicts with `\infer` whether amsmath is loaded or not. I edited the answer to say only that `matrix` has problems.